# what's the equivalent of asyncio event loop with uvloop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, async-await, python-asyncio, uvloop

I have an event loop with a coroutine method using `asyncio`.

I am looking for an equivalent of the following example using [uvloop](https://github.com/MagicStack/uvloop) instead.

Here's a simple `asyncio` event loop example:

```
import asyncio

async def read(**kwargs):
    oid = kwargs.get('oid', '0.0.0.0.0.0')
    time = kwargs.get('time', 1)
    try:
        print('start: ' + oid)
    except Exception as exc:
        print(exc)
    finally:
        await asyncio.sleep(time)
        print('terminate: ' + oid)


def event_loop(configs):
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

    for conf in configs:
        asyncio.ensure_future(read(oid=conf['oid'], time=conf['time']))

    return loop

if __name__ == '__main__':
    snmp_configurations = [
        {'time': 5, 'oid': '1.3.6.3.2.4'},
        {'time': 6, 'oid': '1.3.6.3.5.8'},
    ]  # TODO :: DUMMY
    loop = event_loop(snmp_configurations)
    try:
        loop.run_forever()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
    finally:
        print("Closing Loop")
        loop.close()
```

---

## Question:

- How to reform the above code snippet via [uvloop](https://github.com/MagicStack/uvloop)?
- Is the following changes correct for using [uvloop] [1](https://github.com/MagicStack/uvloop) with more performance?

  ```
   import uvloop

   def event_loop(configs):
       asyncio.set_event_loop_policy(uvloop.EventLoopPolicy())  # TODO: uvloop
       loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

       for conf in configs:
           asyncio.ensure_future(read(oid=conf['oid'], time=conf['time']))

       return loop
  ```

---

[**NOTE**]:

- [uvloop](https://github.com/MagicStack/uvloop) claims that makes asyncio 2-4x faster.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just set event loop policy before you call `asyncio.get_event_loop()`.

```
import asyncio
import uvloop
asyncio.set_event_loop_policy(uvloop.EventLoopPolicy())

async def read(**kwargs):
    oid = kwargs.get('oid', '0.0.0.0.0.0')
    time = kwargs.get('time', 1)
    try:
        print('start: ' + oid)
    except Exception as exc:
        print(exc)
    finally:
        await asyncio.sleep(time)
        print('terminate: ' + oid)


def event_loop(configs):
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

    for conf in configs:
        asyncio.ensure_future(read(oid=conf['oid'], time=conf['time']))

    return loop

if __name__ == '__main__':
    snmp_configurations = [
        {'time': 5, 'oid': '1.3.6.3.2.4'},
        {'time': 6, 'oid': '1.3.6.3.5.8'},
    ]  # TODO :: DUMMY
    loop = event_loop(snmp_configurations)
    try:
        loop.run_forever()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
    finally:
        print("Closing Loop")
        loop.close()
```

Yes, this code is correct. You can set event loop policy after imports.

```
import uvloop
import asyncio
asyncio.set_event_loop_policy(uvloop.EventLoopPolicy())  # TODO  :: uvloop.

def event_loop(configs):

    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

    for conf in configs:
        asyncio.ensure_future(read(oid=conf['oid'], time=conf['time']))

    return loop
```

Comment: Thank for answer, but will it really have an effect on its performance enhancement?

Comment: @BenyaminJafari i never used `uvloop` in production. [This](https://github.com/MagicStack/uvloop/issues/47#issuecomment-239841622) can be helpful.

Comment: [uvloop](https://github.com/MagicStack/uvloop) claims that its speed is 2-4x faster than the `asyncio`. So I will get the profiling with `uvloop` and pure `asyncio`. +1

Comment: @BenyaminJafari these benckmarks never tells you, how faster your application will working. Just test it.

Comment: @BenyaminJafari because your app have specific purposes, but benchmarks code just tests performance between frameworks.

Comment: No, I mean was that get a benchmark in my actual code with the real data by using pure `asyncio` and `uvloop` and choose between them.